# Type collection in a table SQL Server Compact

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce

I work on a program VB.Net using a SQL Server Compact database.

I want to create a table `PRODUCTION` where I can have many employees so I want to create a column as collection of names of employees:

This is the table `Employee` :

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee]
(
   [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
   [nom] NVARCHAR(100),
   [salaire] REAL,
   [date_debut] DATETIME,
   [tache] NVARCHAR(100)
);

ALTER TABLE [Employe] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Employe] PRIMARY KEY ([ID]);
```

The table `PRODUCTION` I want to create :

```
create table production(
   ID int not null identity(1,1),
   date_prod Datetime,
   emp collection (emp1,emp2, ...));
```

Explanation: in the table `Production`, I will have many employees, so I want to insert them in one line of the entry.

Any idea?

Comment: That's not how relational databases work. If you have relations between "Production" and "Employee" tables, you will need to set up a "join" table that defines which "Production" entries have relationships with which "Employees". A *collection* in a relational world is a **table**.

Comment: How can i use join in an insert request ?